# Movie in which a crime lord executes hencemen in his office

Tags: identify-this-movie, crime

I've had these particular scenes in my head for years but I'm curious as to what movie they came from, I must have seen it at least 15 years ago.

If a henchman messed up in someway he would be summoned to the boss' large office. The boss would be flanked by other henchmen and there would also be tarpaulin laid on the floor. He and the boss would have a brief discussion after which the boss would shoot the henchman. The others would then wrap him up in the tarpaulin laid on the floor and take him away. This left the office nice and clean after the bloody execution. Being called to the boss' office when it is set up in this way meant certain death.

There was a scene later in the movie where someone was called in to the office (same setup, tarpaulin on the floor) but after their discussion he instead gets to walk out. I think he was given an opportunity to correct his mistake or came up with some useful information.

Comment: Pretty sure this was one of the muppet movies... ;-)

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of Fur TV, it would not surprise me if a scene like that was in there :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Lethal Weapon 2](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097733/)

> [In Rudd's office, Hans meets Rudd & Vorstedt after losing the
>   Krugerrands in the chase]
>
> Arjen Rudd: Hans, come in.
>
> [points in front of his desk]
>
> Arjen Rudd: Mind the plastic. I'm having some painting done. Well now,
>   the important thing is, are you all right? Any broken bones?
>
> Hans: I'm fine, thank you, Mr. Rudd.
>
> Arjen Rudd: Only a few bumps and bruises, eh?
>
> Hans: Yes, that's all.
>
> Arjen Rudd: Good, good. [pause]
>
> Arjen Rudd: However, we did lose over a million dollars in Krugerrand.
>
> Hans: I know. I'm sorry, Mr. Rudd. It happens.
>
> Arjen Rudd: Ah, it's not your fault. Sometimes these things do not go
>   as planned. As you say, they just happen... eh, Pieter?
>
> [Pieter shoots Hans. He falls dead onto the plastic, and Pieter starts
>   wrapping its edges around his body]
>
> Pieter Vorstedt: You give a new meaning to the phrase "drop-cloth,"
>   Mr. Rudd.

Comment: Slightly different from how I remembered it but that's the one :) [Clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-U_1WImxw0)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it fits entirely to your description, but there is a similar scene in 1989's [*Lethal Weapon 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097733/).

The crime boss that *Riggs* and *Murtaugh* are set against is a South African diplomat, enjoying diplomatic immunity. In one scene he bids one of his minions (or whatever kind of business partner) into his office in which a  big tarpaulin lies. He mentions that he has the painters in his office. But he (or his henchmen?) shoot the guy and wrap him up in the tarpaulin.

Then in a later scene his second in command henchman is standing in the boss' office (though, there isn't a tarpaulin now) and gets a little telling-off from him, for failing to accomplish something. And at one point the henchman looks to the ground and says something like:

> I just want to make sure I'm not standing on a tarpaulin.

Comment: The line is ["I was just checking to see if I was standing on plastic."](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097733/quotes?item=qt0465158)  Nitpicking, I know.